# pathForResource is empty in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, plist

Can't understand, why does this line of the code return `(null)`?

```
// Get path of data.plist file to be created

plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
```

I need to create new plist but can't understand, does the empty file should be created before to get the path to it.. Any ideas?

PS I had only h,m and no plist files in my project now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't create new files in your bundle after deployment. The bundle contains all the resources and files that ship with your app.

Instead, you create new files in your app's Documents folder. To get the documents folder path, you can use a method like this (as included in some of the app template projects):

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

Then you simply append the file name you want to use.

```
NSString *path = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
```

You might also want to have some additional folders in your Documents folder for organizational purposes. You can use `NSFileManager` to do that.

Comment: Just to add to this correct answer, you can also not change any files in the `mainBundle`. All the files in the application bundle on iOS are read only.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, your guess was right - you would need to create a file first.  Here is what the class reference documentation had to say about the method's return value

"Return Value
The full pathname for the resource file or *nil if the file could not be located.*"

You could do something like:

```
if ( [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"] )
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
else
    // Create new file here
```

Also, you could leave out the type extenxion in the method call above if you are searching for a unique file name.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to check wether the file can be found in the bundle. Since you know on forehand that it should be there since you can only add files to the main bundle add compile time. When running your app the bundle is read only a file can't just appear there.